# What does "total about zero" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "total mobile sales are zero". If so, is it paradoxical with what was said in the second sentence, which is $100M?

> According to Fung Global Retail, the warehouse club sector is expected to generate $191 billion in revenues in 2017. But according to Huang, mobile sales for all these competitors **total "about zero**. In just three years we've reached $100M in sales."

[Source](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/08/06/boxed-chieh-huang-wants-to-offer-discount-prices-to-urban-millennials.html)

Comment: Are you sure you understand the meaning in English of _"paradoxical"_? If you mean to say that _zero_ is intended to contrast vividly with the other little company's 100M, that's what it does. It is probably an _exaggeration_, or an _hyperbole_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article says that total mobile sales for Huang's *competitors* is zero.  His *own* mobile sales -- or actually, all his sales, since he's an online distributor -- total $100M.